# How can I suppress the generation of 'trash' from nuget packages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

In a current project, I use lots of nuget packages for all kinds of purposes (Nancy, Unity, Razor..) and they all generate a lot of noise in the application output directory, even on release configuration. How can I prevent those from doing so?

- *.pdb debug databases
- *.xml documentation files
- *.unnecessary locale resources (I have like 20 folders in my output directory for every goddarn langauge..)

Comment: These are not really due to NuGet, but more due to standard Visual Studio build settings.

Answer (score 1):

Check configuration manager for your "release" build and see if all your projects are actually set to release.  If they are, check each projects properties, on the build tab see what constants are defined (not sure if this would affect things or not), click the advanced button, see what the debug info is there.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get rid of those things (after all, they are there for a reason) I'd suggest defining post build events in your project properties to have them deleted by Visual Studio once your project has been built successfully.

Make sure to use the appropriate macros to target the correct directories. Also, uncheck the creation of DEBUG and TRACE constants and XML documentation to suppress the creation of *.pdb and *.xml files for your own project.

[MSDN on build events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2s2128d.aspx)